# Why is electric current during charging battery equal to vb1-vb2/r1+r2 and any resistance in circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, voltage, batteries, intensity

Why when we connect two batteries in series but in opposite directions current equals vb1-vb2/r1+r2. I can't understand why we subtract the current of the smaller battery from the greater battery. I know that because they are in opposite directions but why when currents are in opposite directions we subtract thats my question. I want anyone to explain for me what happens when two electric currents that are in opposite directions meet. I hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

> I can't understand why we subtract the current of the smaller battery
> from the greater battery.

You're not subtracting currents. You're subtracting the voltage of the lower voltage battery from the higher voltage of the higher voltage battery to get the net voltage, and then dividing the net voltage by the total internal resistance to get the current, per Ohm's law.

Hope this helps.